# Program can't recognize a character

Tags: c++, string

I have a little problem with compression of two characters.

```
for(int i=0; i<initializer.size(); i++)
{
    char letter;
    letter = initializer[stringIter];
    if(letter == '+')
    {
        std::cout << "+";
    }
    else if(letter == '-')
    {
        std::cout << "-";
    }
    else if(letter == 'F')
    {
        std::cout << "F";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << letter << " UNKNOWN";}
    }
    initializer = F + F - F - F + F
}
```

And when I'm trying to print the character, I have a little question mark instead of the real character, and almost every character is *unknown*.

Comment: shouldn't it be `initializer[i]`? Or add the declaration of `stringIter`

Comment: Perfect time to learn [how to use a debugger](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and step through the code so you can see exactly what's going on.

Comment: stringIter is i;) Its the same value.

Comment: Where is `stringIter` incremented in the loop?  I don't see it declared as a reference to `i`, so how can it be the same?

Comment: The code as posted will not compile, even if embedded in something else: There are 5 `{`s and 6 `}`s (the [curly bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket) (`{`}s)) are not balanced). Something has probably been left out (and equally badly formatted).

Answer (score -1):

This way will work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string initializer = "F+F-F-F+F";
    for(int i=0; i<initializer.size(); i++)
    {
        char letter;
        letter = initializer[i];
        if(letter == '+')
        {
            std::cout << "+";
        }
        else if(letter == '-')
        {
            std::cout << "-";
        }
        else if(letter == 'F')
        {
            std::cout << "F";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << letter << " UNKNOWN";
        }
    }
}
```

*debugging* shows that he found a \342 \210 \222 char as letter. But why?...

So what’s the problem? It is really chars.

Comment: Lolz.................................. it's function not in main and initializer is passing to it. I have wrote like this to show its value.....

Comment: And so? I have fixed your iterator mistake. If you insert this code into notmain function it will work.

Comment: Watch to this line: letter=initializer[i];